# Storing the selection from a SQLite filled listview as a string

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

In my android app, I have a normal few listview using `String []` but I have one listview from an **SQLite** database. It shows it fine, that isn't the issue. The issue is logging which option I have press, as it just seems to log `android.database.sqlite.sqlitecursor@????` and when I use a toast to show the string

I have to code to do what I want to do with the option name

So it would be really helpful if someone could just help me with storing the option name in a string and use it in a toast... as that is the way I test code. Thanks

I post the code that fills the listview below if that helps

FavouritesScreen.java... using the SQLite values in the listview

```
final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, //context
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, db.getValues(), //Cursor
    new String[] {"SocietyName"}, new int[] {
        android.R.id.text1
    });
list.setAdapter(adapter);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
    String favname = (String)((Cursor) list).getString(position);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), favname, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
});
```

MyDBAdapter.java... getting the values from the SQLite database

```
public Cursor getValues() {
  if (!isOpen()) {
    open();
  }
  System.out.println("3a");
  Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, "Favourites", // table name
  new String[] {
    "_id", "SocietyName"
  }, // select clause
  null, // where clause
  null, // where clause parameters
  null, // group by
  null, // having
  null, // order by
  null); // limit
  System.out.println("4a");
  return mCursor;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list` is a ListView not a Cursor (I would've expected this to throw an exception.)

```
String favname = (String) ((Cursor) list).getString(position);
```

Fetch the Cursor first, then call `getString()` on the column that you are interested in:

```
String favname = ((Cursor) list.getItemAtPosition(position)).getString(columnIndex);
/* I assume the column you want is 1 */
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, what does the 'columnIndex' relate to?

Comment: A Cursor contains as many columns as you ask for, you used `new String[] { "_id", "SocietyName" }`.  If you want to display the `"SocietyName"` data use `getString(1)`, so `columnIndex` is the index of the column in your String Array.

Answer (score 0):

android.database.sqlite.sqlitecursor@????'

```
String favname = (String) ((Cursor) list).getString(position);
```

is def. not giving you a string, but a SQLLite cursor. Instead use the cursor object to get the string you need.

You should probably be getting a hold of the Adapter object associated to the list, then ask for the cursor, then ask for what's on the position.

Or better yet, use this guy:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0
```

the AdapterView object. Ask that 'arg0' object for what you need at position.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), arg0.getItemAtPosition(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```